# When I try to Port Sample Android app into Blackberry 10 Dev Alpha simulator I Get Error

Tags: simulator, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

Connecting 192.168.176.128 to ADB failed!
Please check if the Android player was fully started when you got this error. If not, you can either increase the Android player launch timeout on the BlackBerry->BlackBerry Android Development Tools preference page or wait until the Android player is fully started and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This means that Eclipse, or more specifically the BlackBerry Android tools plugin for Eclipse, could not connect to the ADB (Android Debug Bridge) service on the BlackBerry device.

There are a number of reasons for this:

1. The Android Runtime and associated services including ADB did not load in time. The default timeout is 5 seconds and if you have not run any Android apps on your BlackBerry it will take more like 20 seconds to load the first time.
2. The Android Runtime has crashed. In which case you will need to reboot your device. My preferred method for this is a '3 finger reset' which means hold down the power button, volume up and volume down buttons for 10 seconds in order to do a full reset.

Comment: I tried with your solution but still the error is exists. I am not able to load app on BB10 device.